# Merging JSON object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have JSON object like this:

```
 jsonData =[
{
  'ApplicationName':'Chrome',
  'env':'Linux',
  'status':'Work'
},
{
  'ApplicationName':'Chrome',
  'env':'Window',
  'status':'Work'
},
  {
  'ApplicationName':'Chrome',
  'env':'IOS',
  'status':'Not Work'
}];
```

I want to merge in the optimal way so that my returned JSON object look this:

```
  jsonData =[
{
  'ApplicationName':'Chrome',
  'GroupedEnv':[{'env':'Linux',status:'Work'},{'env':'Window',status:'Work'},{'env':'IOS',status:'Not Work'}]

}];
```

Comment: @NinaScholz : Using loops I can do it, but I am looking for optimal way of doing it

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. *(And if that* were *JSON, it would be invalid JSON.)*

Comment: you could add what you have.

Comment: Programming is all about loops and branches, so what optimal way do you think there is that does not involve loops?

Comment: @Freeman Lambda I dont want to go for o(n^2) complexity.

Comment: So this isn't really a merge, you want to group by `ApplicationName` right?

Comment: @matt Burland : Ya right grouping is more appropriate word for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very quick example:

```
const reduced = jsonData.reduce((acc, curr) => {

    var appName = curr.ApplicationName;
    acc[appName] = acc[appName] || [];
    acc[appName].push({
        env: curr.env,
        status: curr.env
    });

    return acc;

}, {});

const asArray = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(reduced).map((prop) => {

    return {
        ApplicationName: prop,
        GroupedEnv: reduced[prop]
    };

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion